# How to access reference count of cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, memory-management

Suppose I want to track the reference count of a `cv::Mat` by simply printing it in an executable.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv>

int main()
{
    cv::Mat m;
    int refCount = (m.u)->refcount; // <--- Crashes here!
    std::cout << refCount << std::endl;
}
```

If I run the above code I get a runtime error:

> unknown file: SEH exception with code 0xc0000005 thrown in the test body.

What am I doing wrong?

Code reference: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.x/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" -- trying to access the internal data holder of a `Mat` that doesn't hold any. (as in the `Mat` is empty, since you only used the default constructor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`refcount` is a member of an `cv::Mat::u` which is the **internal** data holder of the `cv::Mat`.

Usually you shouldn't access it.

If you have a good reason for that, you should be aware that `cv::Mat::u` is allocated only if the `cv::Mat` refers to some data.
In your case it is **default constructed** to an empty one and so `cv::Mat::u` is **null**, causing an access violation when you dereference it.

In order to fix it you can check for **null**:

```
int refCount = (m.u) ? ((m.u)->refcount) : 0;
```

Note that if your `cv::Mat` was not empty, e.g.:

```
cv::Mat m(3, 4, CV_8UC3);
```

Your approach would have worked.

---

A side note:
`#include <opencv2/opencv>` should be `#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>`.